# Greek letters not displaying correctly

Tags: siunitx, greek, latex3

I have trouble with setting up greek letters to be used in SI unit. I need to set up the `microseconds` unit for my measured value. However, any solution I found online straigh just failed on my end. This is my document preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[shorthands=off,czech]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=iso-numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lab03.bib}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{attachfile}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    detect-mode,
    detect-family,
    detect-inline-family=math,
    group-separator={ },
    group-minimum-digits={3},
    output-decimal-marker={,}
}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\title{Laboratorní úloha č.~2 \textemdash\ Výkonové polovodičové systémy\\ \large \emph{Měření na~napěťovém střídači}}
\author{Marek Poláček (POL0423)\\ VŠB \textendash\ Technická univerzita Ostrava\\ Fakulta elektrotechniky a~informatiky}
\date{\today}
```

And this is how the greek letter shows up:
[image: Greek letter <code>μ</code> shows as <code>ţ</code>]

Basically, `\textmu` inside `\si{}` displays `μ` as `ţ`. When I use `\mu`, it displays correct glyph, but slanted, which is wrong. I need the upright variant. Placing directly `μ` in the code makes thing even worse, it doesn't display at all. Tried using `textgreek` package, didn't help at all. I am running out of options here and I need to finish it as soon as possible.

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should either use `\micro\second` or `\us`. And it should be `\SI{76,43}{\micro\second}` (not with `\num` and `\si`).

Comment: Please post the text of your MWE, not an image of it. It’s difficult to enter and test.

Comment: @egreg Learning something new, again. Thank you, this is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Off-topic but very important: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: @Sebastiano Since I do not flush equations to left or anything else, I do not need to swap the `$$` for better alternative, since it won't make any visual change. However, thanks for suggestion, might as well use in future 

Comment: I'm using `\SI{1}{\micro}` and it still turns up as 1ţ in the PDF.